# Laravel Livewire, How to apply select2 in dynamic fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

**Blade File**

```
<div id="for_item" wire:ignore>
         <select wire:model="purchaseRequests.{{$index}}.item_id" class="select2 select2-sm" data-container="#for_item">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            @if(isset($itemList))
                @foreach ($itemList as $item)
                   <option value="{{$item['id']}}">{{$item['name']}}</option>
                @endforeach
            @endif
         </select>
    </div>



@push('scripts')
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.select2').on('change', function (e) {
            let elementName = $(this).attr('id');
            var data = $(this).select2("val");
            @this.set(elementName, data);
        });

    });

</script>
@endpush
```

I have the button that will add additional row, the select2 is working properly in static field but when i click the button to generate row the select2 is not working.

Answer (score 1):

**Component**

```
public function addRequestDetail()
{
 $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('reApplySelect2');
}
```

**Blade**

```
@push('scripts')
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.addEventListener('reApplySelect2', event => {
            $('.select2').select2();
        });
    });
</script>
@endpush
```